# GeoServer, Label rotation on rotation of map

Tags: geoserver, labeling, cesium

I am using GeoServer with cesium for rendering Vector of data. Every thing is working fine. I have styled it properly with labels.

Now there is a requirement that as we rotate the map(on mobile phone), labels should not be rotated, as similar to google map.
But this is not happening as labels are stick to tiles.

I did the google a lot but could not find the solution.

Please help.

Comment: If your vector tiles are working properly, you'll need to look into cesium, as styling us done client side. Can you provide more info about your use of cesium?

Comment: I have done styling by using Geoserver's CSS module (SLD), and just calling the WMS from cesium.

Comment: The whole web page rotates when rotating the phone so why do you need to render rotated map tiles, as north remains up?

Comment: Actually, when user rotates map(by pinching with fingures), text is also rotating along with tiles, and user has to rotates  it's phone as well.

Comment: If you rotate the map on desktop (middle mouse drag, or ctrl-left-drag) do the labels also rotate?  You may be seeing raster labels if so.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WMS in Cesium, you're not using vector tiles, you're viewing rendered images.

Read more about vector tiles here: http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/vectortiles/index.html

Note that you'll need to do your styling client-side.

Comment: It means , I need to use vector tiles, instead of wms. If I will use vector tiles with client side styling.I am not aware that how to do labeling on client side(please guide), also I am using the data for country(including road,places,district,buildings) downloaded from OSM, doing this it will not slow down the rendering ?

Comment: If you only want rotated labels, then you could just set labels up as vectors and use WMS for boundaries. Its probably worth doing it all the same though, as vectors. Note that MapBox do vector basemaps including labels, and this is simpler than setting up Cesium and GeoServer. In fact, im not sure that Cesium supports vector tiles: https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/2132

Comment: I have gone through the link of "open geo suite" provieded by you. I understood that I need to render vector tiles. But I am not able to get Map Box-Vector tile in GeoServer which is the fastest on performance wise. It seems that this is avialable only in GeoServer downloaded from openGeosite which seems to be paid. I am using GeoServer 2.9.1 and could find the this format. Please help. Also , I would like to know that if I will use styling in client side, will I be able to set these parameters in OL-3 Style "-gt-label-conflict-resolution", "-gt-label-fit-goodness", "-gt-label-all-group"

Comment: Hi @VineetArora, you can grab the plugin directly here: http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.9.x/community-latest/